# Sorting non-nested array of data from adjacency model

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, adjacency-list, adjacency-list-model

I have an array of data fetched from a database table that uses the adjacency model to build a heirarchy of topics. Each record contains the following fields:

- 'id' - a unique AI id.
- 'name' - a display name.
- 'parent_id' - the id of a parent topic (can be null for root topics)

The array comes from the database un-nested and sorted by id as you would expect. The 'id' field is random and abritary and cannot be relied upon to produce a useful order. I am seeking a way to sort the array using the parent_id so that it is in the correct adjacency order but without the end result being nested into sub arrays. The list would look like below:

- **RootTopicA**
- ATopic1
- ATopic2
- *Child1ofATopic2*
- *Child2ofATopic2*
- ATopic3
- **RootTopicB**
- BTopic1
- BTopic2
- etc.

Any help or a pointer to an example (even in a different language) would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your array structure? I understand, that above list is your desired output, but what is the input?

Comment: its an array of records from the database array(array(id=>1,name=>RootTopicA,parent_id=>null),array(id=>2,name=>ATopic1, parent_id=>1)) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field for example `sort` in which you would store the order of the same ids in the category.

The other solution is to sort them (in SQL) by `ORDER BY parent_id, id` or combining the two, `ORDER BY sort`, using JOINs like (not tested):

```
SELECT object.id, object.sort, parent.id, parent.sort
FROM objects AS object
LEFT JOIN objects AS parent ON object.parent=parent.id
ORDER BY parent.sort, object.sort;
```

assuming that `objects` is your table name, the same table is `object` as the main object, and `parent` as object that is its parent (you need it to get `sort` of parent).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is what I was looking for. There should be sufficient information in the parent_id column to arrange the data into parents, children and sub children without an additional sort column. The final order is unimportant (could be alphabetical or by id) as long as each parent has its children beneath it. Ideally I'd like to work with the array not queries so I can wrap it into a class/function for use elsewhere.

Comment: If I were to sort by parent_id I would get a list like this RootTopicA,RootTopicB,Atopic1,Atopic2,Atopic3,Btopic1,Btopic2,child1ofatopic2,child2ofatopic2